# Multi valued attribute in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entities:

```
____________________             ____________________
|  Activity        |             |  Benefit         |
------------------ |             |------------------|
| activityId:long  |-------------| benefitId: long  |
| activity:varchar |             | activityId: long |
| ....             |             | benefit: varchar |
--------------------             -------------------|
```

Can I map this into Hibernate so I end up with this:

```
@Entity
class Activity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String activity;


    private List<String> benefits;
}
```

Comment: From my experience with other ORMs, you might want to look for a feature called OneToMany or something like that.

Comment: I know about onetomany, what I want is to map the whole table into just a list of string

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `@ElementCollection` tag.

Here's what your code would look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Activity")
class Activity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="activity_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name") 
    private String activity;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
        name = "Benefit",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activityId")
    )
    private List<String> benefits;
```

}

Though I would call the table `ActivitiesBenefits` instead of `Benefit` to make it clear that that table will store pairs of activities and benefits. Also, there is no need for a `benefitId`, since a benefit is a weak entity (it cannot exist without an activity), so you can drop that too.

Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Answer (score 1):

Hi I could find one way in which you could do it. Below is code for same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Activity")
class Activity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="activity_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name") 
    private String activity;

    @OneToMany
    @Formula("(select CONCAT(benefitId, activityId, benefit) from Benefit b where b.activityId = activity_id)")
    private List<String> benefits;
}
```

I am using a sql returning list of benefits and then concatenate it and store it in our benefits list.
The string in formula is SQL(not HQL) so its column names and not filed member names.

Comment: Really the only field from benefit I want is the benefit string, even so, how would I manage update of this relation using your solution?